# How to generate random fixed point number in matlab

Tags: matlab

If I want to generate a random series of fixed point number after decimal and also before decimal

for example

> 0.112,1.110,1.520,-2.540,-0.001

etc in given range suppose [-4,4].

Is there any command to generate such random number and store in any array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To Generate values from the uniform distribution on the interval `[a, b]`.

- `r = a + (b-a).*rand(size,1);`

Example :

```
>> r = -4 + (4-(-4)).*rand(10,1) % 10 random numbers

r =

    3.6952
   -3.9629
    2.1993
    2.5384
    2.9496
   -3.3245
   -0.8017
   -1.9210
    2.4005
   -0.5487
```

Comment: thanks yaar instant response i like this website but sir can you tell how can i decide the fixed decimal number after decimal point for example: if 1 want 3 value after decimal(1.302) or if i want to four decimal number after decimal (2.3331) and how to store in array of row means r=[0.10 1.02 1.05.....]

Comment: sir again i got one more query the data automatically change  when our running this code i don't want to change this number i want to  use same random generated number whenever i will run code how can i do that

Comment: @ShreyasPatel to answer you first question _"how to store in array of row mean.."_ Take transpose of Use : `r'`. Also don't think that displayed number are having exactly 4 decimal places, they are in fact represented internally. The display can be changed using [`format`](http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/ref/format.html) command. Other questions may be on other post, I don't wanna populate comment section leading a chat room eventually